# GeoLite2 database gets corrupt when added to war

Tags: maven

Like the question [GeoLite2 database gets corrupt when added to jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449733/geolite2-database-gets-corrupt-when-added-to-jar), I got the error from the WAR file with the following steps:

1. `mvn package` to copy GeoLite2-City.mmdb from `src/main/resources/GeoLite2-City.mmdb` to war file under `WEB-INF/classes/GeoLite2-City.mmdb`
2. GeoLite2-City.mmdb was changed in the first step `mvn package`

I tried the plugin `maven-resources-plugin` as https://stackoverflow.com/a/34454312/1086907, but GeoLite2-City.mmdb is still changed by `mvn package`

How to troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **maven-war-plugin** can actually also  *filter* that file.

Just like for the **maven-resources-plugin**, you can add that *mmdb* file extension as [an additional extension not to be filtered](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#nonFilteredFileExtensions):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>mmdb</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Glad it helped. To help future visitors knowing that this question is answered, please click on the grey check and turn it green (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)